# Start all terminal sessions within /usr/bin/script

Tags: bash, logs, bashrc

I would like to expend some disk space recording all input and output to my terminal sessions; `/usr/bin/script` appears to be fairly good at that. I would like to make it so all new shell sessions (Currently I use`/bin/bash`) could start inside a `script` session that logged to a file by the name of say `~/.log/$(date --iso-8601=second).log`

I've tried calling `script` at the end of my .bashrc file but recall it basically crashing and making opening a new shell impossible.

Any ideas on a possible way to keep this kind of record? I already have an ["Eternal bash history"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history) but just knowing the inputs is not always enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think putting it at the bottom of your rcfile would do much good - all of the state you declared beforehand would get wiped out when `script` loaded a new shell until *it* tried to load the rcfile and etc and etc forever. I just made it work on my terminal like:

```
$ x=;bash --rcfile /dev/fd/3 3<<\$x
    export S_LOG=~/".log/$(date --iso-8601=second).log"
    exec   script -aeqfc "bash   --rcfile /dev/fd/3 -i" "$S_LOG" \
3<<""
    alias success='echo it worked'
    PS1='script $ '
    exec 3<&-

$x
script $ success
it worked
script $ cat "$S_LOG"
Script started on Mon Dec 14 15:43:28 2015
script $ success
it worked
script $ cat "$S_LOG"
script $
```

And so I think you'd do better to locate it at the *head* of your rc-file, and then `exec` a new shell to read the rest of it *after* the point you call the new shell.